# Annotate List of Integers field with JPA to persist it as JSON

Tags: json, hibernate, jpa, objectmapper

I have a List of Integers that I would like to save in a database like a JSON array in one field.

My current entity:

```
@Entity
public class ShortestPath {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String path;

    ///...
}
```

Now I can do it like this:

```
List<Integer> shortestPath = ...

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(shortestPath);

repository.save(new ShortestPath(jsonString));
```

In my database I receive this picture:

[image]

With this approach I need to convert String to a List again with ObjectMapper after getting an object from a database.

Is this possible to somehow **annotate** my entity field **path** to transform list on numbers to a JSON string and visa versa without additional manipulations with ObjectMapper?

So that my entity be:

```
@Entity
public class ShortestPath {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Some_Json_Annotation
    private List<Integer> path;

    ///...
}
```

Comment: I dont think such annotation is available or possible.

Comment: Maybe you can define a custom type as documented here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#types-custom-ut